# How to iterate thru array in object, updating object with database calls for each array value?

Tags: arrays, node.js, database, loops

Using NodeJS, trying to update an object using other values stored in the object model.  The object contains an array with values that are used to query a set of other values from MariaDB and then update the original object.
Node iterates through all of the array values sequentially, then iterates through each db call sequentially, then returns the object, but with no updates.

```
local object = {
    "type":null,
    "id":null,
    "code":null,
    "title":null,
    "description":null,
    "attrs":[
        {
            "attr_id":null,
            "attr_data_type":null,
            "attr_control_type":null,
            "fixed_list":null,
            "attr_fixed_list_values":[
                {
                    "attr_id":null,
                    "value_id:":null,
                    "fixed_list_value":null
                }
            ],
            "attr_name":null,
            "attr_value":null
        }
    ],
    "mv_attrs":[
        {
            "attr_id":null,
            "attr_data_type":null,
            "attr_name":null,
            "attr_values":[]
        }
    ]
};
```

Callbacks do not work.  Nested callbacks do not work.  Q library doesn't appear to be an option.

```
// Passed in object is 'lo' (i.e. local object)

//iterate through each object attribute
    for(var a = 0; a < Object.keys(lo.attrs).length-1; a++) {

//get fixed value list for each attribute
        if (lo.attrs[a].fixed_list === 'Y') {

        const sql = 'select aflv.attr_id, aflv.value_id, aflv.attr_value as fixed_list_value from attr_fixed_list_values aflv where aflv.attr_id = ' + lo.attrs[a].attr_id;


            connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } else {
                    lo.attrs[a]["attr_fixed_list_values"]=rows;
                }
            })
    }
}
return (lo);  //at this point, lo has been updated
```

The goal is to populate the array of fixed values

```
"attr_fixed_list_values":[
    {
        "attr_id":null,
        "value_id:":null,
        "fixed_list_value":null
    }
],
```

for each attribute in the attrs array.

Answer (score -1):

local object = { "type":null, "id":null, "code":null, "title":null, "description":null, "attrs":[ { "attr_id":null, "attr_data_type":null, "attr_control_type":null, "fixed_list":null, "attr_fixed_list_values":[ { "attr_id":null, "value_id:":null, "fixed_list_value":null } ], "attr_name":null, "attr_value":null } ], "mv_attrs":[ { "attr_id":null, "attr_data_type":null, "attr_name":null, "attr_values":[] } ] };

Callbacks do not work. Nested callbacks do not work. Q library doesn't appear to be an option.

// Passed in object is 'lo' (i.e. local object)

//iterate through each object attribute for(var a = 0; a < Object.keys(lo.attrs).length-1; a++) {

//get fixed value list for each attribute if (lo.attrs[a].fixed_list === 'Y') {

```
const sql = 'select aflv.attr_id, aflv.value_id, aflv.attr_value as fixed_list_value from attr_fixed_list_values aflv where aflv.attr_id = ' + lo.attrs[a].attr_id;


    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            lo.attrs[a]["attr_fixed_list_values"]=rows;
        }
    })
```

}
} return (lo)